# difference between strncat and memcpy

Tags: c, string, memcpy

Please find below code snippet. Is there any chance wherein `strncat` and `memcpy` will have different values in `pDBVal`. If so, Please explain.

```
memcpy(pDBVal, pHash, 20); 

strncat(pDBVal, cBinSalt, 16);

memcpy(pDBVal+20,cBinSalt,16);
```

Ideally output in pDBVal will be same. Also please explain the difference in execution of both the functions

Comment: They are completely different. It looks like you are using trial and error to solve your problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do not use `strXX` functions for binary data. Do not use `memXX` functions for strings. That is the difference. For "explaining the difference in execution", read any [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) [guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strncat` is supposed to be used for string concatenation, so in

```
strncat(pDBVal, cBinSalt, 16);
```

If the length of `cBinSalt` is less than `16`, only the content up to `'\0'` is copied.